# recursive code in java for calculation of money account in a bank

Tags: java

I want to implement a recursive code in java for calculation of money account in a bank after some years of investing ... here is my code

```
public static double computeCapital(double capital, int years, double interestRate) {
   if (years == 0) {
      return capital;
   } else {
      double newcapital = capital * Math.pow(interestRate,year);
      return computeCapital(newcapital , years+1 , interestRate);
   }
}
```

Is my code correct?
thanks

Comment: No, your code won't pass compilation, and even if you change `year` to `years`, you'll probably get StackOverflowError.

Comment: Please use [Code Review Forum](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Shouldn't it be years-1? Otherwise the recursion will take a very long time..

Comment: How to correct it?

Comment: Burkhard why it is years - 1 ? is not that should be calculating until it reaches the desired year and then stop !

Comment: Because you don't start at year 0, you start at year 3 or something (if it's 3 years you want to calculate) and then you should count down to 0 so your if statement is true and your recursion terminates.

Comment: Mr. M 33 OK thank you brother ,, now it is clear ,, God bless you

Comment: i do not think just changing to "years-1" will not be correct. you have also to remove  "double newcapital = capital * Math.pow(interestRate,year);"

Comment: for ex. capital = 100 years = 3 interestrate = 10%
then your output will be 
100* Math.pow(1.1,3)*Math.pow(1.1,2)*Math.pow(1.1,1); which is not correct

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. That's what the answers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public static double computeCapital(double capital, int years, double interestRate) {
    if (years == 0) {    
    return capital; 
    }
    else{
    return computeCapital(capital, years-1, interestRate)*(1+interestRate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stop condition is years == 0.

Your recursion starts with years and calculates the capital for years - 1.

If you want to know your capital in 3 years, you will calculate the capital in 2 years and multiply it by the interestrate.
The capital in 2 years is the capital in 1 year multiplied by the interestrate.

Have a look at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).